# average point on each bin pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes temperature(y) and ratio(x). In each dataframe I have 60 columns corresponding to 60 different machines that measure both parameters.

for now I have a plot for each machine of y vs x, as follow:

```
for column in ratio.columns:
    x = ratio[column]
    y = temperature[column]

    if len(x) != len(y):
        x_ind = x.index
        y_ind = y.index
        common_ind = x_ind.intersection(y_ind)
        x = x[common_ind]
        y = y[common_ind]

    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.savefig("plot" +column+".png")
    plt.clf()
```

because I have a lot of data points, I want to do binning for each machine and to do an average on each bin, so that I will have an average point of y for each bin.
x is between 0 and 1 and I want to bin every 0.05, which gives 20 bins.

I got an histogram for each machine by doing:
        for x in ratio.columns:
        ratio.hist(column = x, bins = 20)
but this is only giving number of events vs ratio.

how can I link the temperature dataframe
I am new to pandas and I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1):

mask bin every 20

`mask = my_df.index//20`

then use groupby and agg

`my_df.groupby(mask).agg(['mean'])`

Comment: so my_df would be ratio here. what about temperature, I don't see where you take it into account